# AJAX parameter still null

Tags: c#, ajax, razor

I have a simple modal form used to insert data; when i submit data, i correctly go to my method but the parameter still null value.

This is my Razor code:

```
<form id="SaveKeyForm" asp-page-handler="SaveExternalKEY" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="post">
<div class="modal-body">
    <input name="IsValid" type="hidden" value="@ViewData.ModelState.IsValid.ToString()" />
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="wItem.Guid"></label>
        <input asp-for="wItem.Guid" name="GUID" class="form-control" id="modalCustomerGUID" readonly required />
        <span asp-validation-for="wItem.Guid" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.Hidden("External_Key_Type_ID", "")
        <select class="custom-select mr-sm-2" asp-items="_KeyOptions" name="Selected_Key_Type_ID"><option selected>Choose</option></select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="wExternal_ID.ExternalKey"></label>
        <input asp-for="wExternal_ID.ExternalKey" name="ExternalKEY" class="form-control" required/>
        <span asp-validation-for="wExternal_ID.ExternalKey" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    <button type="submit" id="saveKey" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
</div>
```

This is my JS code:

```
 $("#saveKey").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    console.log('Ajax submit');        
    var form = $(this).parents('.modal').find('form');
    var formAction = form.attr('action');
    var fdata = form.serialize();        
    console.log(fdata);

    var sdata = { GUID: 'fdsfas' };

    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: formAction,            
        data: sdata,
        dataType: "text",
        processData: false,
        headers: {
            RequestVerificationToken:
                $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val()
        },
        statusCode: {
            404: function () {
                console.log("page not found");
            },
            200: function () {
                console.log("Status Ok");
            }
        }

    }).done(function (result) {
        console.log('Result: ' + result);            
    });
});
```

and this is my method:

```
    public IActionResult OnPostSaveExternalKEY(string GUID)
    {
        try
        {
            return new OkResult();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            return  new StatusCodeResult(404);
        }
    }

}
```

i have try to:
- pass data as 'fdata' variable: still null
- pass fixed data as 'sdata' variable: still null
- try to Json serialize: still null

If i use jquery-ajax-unobtrusive, i can pass correctly value to my method, but i cannot manage error message in modal form and url change.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Have you tried `data: JSON.stringify(sdata)` with `contentType: 'application/json'`?

Comment: Yes, still null.